# qt4.7: Can't see the text of QLabel derived class

Tags: qt4

I derived from QLabel class. I want to redefine some events(e.g. mousePressEvent and paintEvent). But in this case the content of QLabel derived class(e.g. text) is invisible. SetEnabled and SetVisible are not helpful. Can u tell me why client area of label is invisible?(but the reaction on events is ok).

```
class PaintRect : public QLabel {
public:
    explicit PaintRect(QWidget *parent = 0);
/*
private:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
*/
};
```

If uncomment events defenition and create object and show() them, the client area of object is invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to call the QLabel constructor from your PaintRect constructor?

Or maybe you need to call the parent's paintEvent from the PaintRect's paintEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! I understand why the client area of label was invisible. I redefined a paintEvent with no code. There is 2 ways: call base class paint to draw text and oters or do it in redefined paintEvent.